# What is a good starter camera for under $350?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, low-budget

I have a very limited budget. I have $350 [USD]. If I buy a used DSLR Camera and it doesn't work, it would be a huge loss. If I buy a compact digital camera, would I be able to do DSLR things like blur the background and focus on the subject.  Which cameras do you suggest?

Comment: I just realized what the original title was... haha

Comment: Yea, one of the mod mates have changed that.

Comment: @Kimzi: you don't have to be a mod to edit posts here. Anyone can do it (with approval from another member if your reputation isn't high enough). If you feel the edit doesn't reflect your intentions clearly, feel free to comment and/or edit further yourself.

Comment: @Kimzi, if you could clarify what photography you're interested in that might be enabled only by having a DSLR (the "DSLR things"), and conversely what you're worried about not working, I think we can be of more help to you.

Answer (score 6):

**For around $340 you could pick up a [Canon S95](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSHNGS)** that is a very capable camera, but still fits in your pocket and can do things similar to a DSLR(debatable).

This is a very opinionated answer, but I believe this camera is a great way to start with photography, and learn what areas limit your artistic vision - then allow you to make a better choice when purchasing a DSLR. This could be said with nearly every camera. You just need to pick it up, and use it enough to find the limits.

This camera in particular is very full featured, and will give you excellent shots in most conditions while still giving you full manual control of things like aperture, shutter speed, and ISO.

If you really are serious about learning photography, just pick up any used DSLR, a used Canon 20D comes to mind, it would fit your budget, and probably allow you to pick up a 50mm f/1.8 and still stay within budget. For a beginner you **don't want to worry about the equipment so much as just putting in the time and learning**.

Comment: Seems like I have the same opinionated view ;) The S95 and S90 which precedes (may still be available and nearly identical) have the best interface for manual control I've soon so far. Thanks to the F/2 lens, you can really get creative.

Comment: +1: I got my S95 a week ago and I like it very much. I have almost the same control over the camera as with my DSLR (Nikon D70). Downsides verus a DSLR: not as responsive (DSLR fires in virtually the same moment you press the shutter the s95 takes a little moment), and with a DSLR you have better access to all the parameters. The DSLR doesn't fit into my pocket, though.

Answer (score -3):

I've got everything here, thanks to all of the mates who answered. Making this discussion not longer, I'll have 2 things remaining to ask all of you.

1. How can a simple camera act like dslr? Like how would we manual focus? You got any video on that? How to know which camera will do that? (Sorry, if it's nonsense)
2. From my selection I select these cameras.

   1. Canon SX230 HS
   2. Nikon S8100
   3. Nikon S9100

Above seems to be fit in my budget, if there are any better than your suggested let me know.

Thanks once again.

Comment: You would want to look for a camera with manual focus as an option. If you are interested in a video on how to do this, I would just search Youtube "manual focus camera XYZ" and see if you return any results for that camera or a similar one.

Comment: @Kimzi: for the first part of the question in your answer/comment here, I suggest breaking it into individual questions about specific features or abilities, and asking each of those as a separate new question. (Multiple straightforward questions are much better for the site than one big multipart one.)